# Multiple parameters (columns rows) REST API

Tags: c#, .net, rest, serialization

I'm working on a proof of concept of a RESTful API service for my employer, but have found myself slightly stuck.

I've got it working on GET-requests, both getting all the data from a view and getting some data based on parameters (id). However since the stored procedure has a **TONNE** of fields (140 columns) I'm a bit at a loss about how to handle any inserts / update statements that would have equally as many rows in their queries.

I've been looking around for solutions to handling multiple parameters, but I fail to see the benefit of using a "?param=args" per row. Is there a way to make the URL look slightly more formatted by passing in objects or something of the sort? If so, how would you go about (stress)testing that?

Any suggestions and advice would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Is passing the data in the request body an option?

Comment: I haven't thought of that. How would you go about doing that? I read a bit of it after you mentioned it just now, but I fail to see how you would test that locally on an MVC project since you can't modify the body of a request in a URL directly, can you?

Comment: If you are sending the data over the REST service, you need to first store the data in a collection (List, Dictionary or any custom IEnumerable collection). A collection of data would be easily parsed into JSON format and can be sent over the REST service (using POST method). However, there may be some restrictions/complications over the size of JSON which you need to consider for both the client and the REST service.

Comment: Why are you so concerned about the URI structure? It is for the REST client and not for human consumption... Don't confuse the URI of the REST service with the URI you see in the browser. You should never see a REST service URI in any browser.

Answer (score 0):

Example of passing data in the request body:

Creating your body content:

```
var example = "Hello World";

Dictionary<string, string> pairs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
pairs.Add("ExampleData", example);

var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(pairs);
var response = await PostAsync(YourRouteToRestApi, formContent);
```

The Post method would look something like that:

```
public async Task<string> PostAsync(string apiCall, HttpContent data)
{
   var client = new HttpClient();
   try
   {
      var response = await client.PostAsync(apiCAll, data);
      return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      // do something
   }
}
```

Now you have a clean url, without hundreds of `?param=args`.

If it is possible to encapsulate all your paramater into an object, or if you create a `Collection` which holds your parameters (like *Souvik Ghosh* suggested). You could pass this object or collection in your `PosAsync` method instead of the `Dictionary` data.
So the `HttpClient` will take care of the Json serialization.

In your WebApi you would get this data like this:

```
public void Post([FromBody]YourObject stuff)
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: This all seems good, but what about if the keypair is anything but string, string? Wouldn't the conversion to and from string create quite a lot of processing overhead?

Comment: What if you pass a whole object in the `PostAsync` method and let `HttpClient` handle the serialization into Json (like in my updated answer)? Would this be better?

Comment: So if I understand this correctly I'd create a collection and serialize it on the client-side before sending that collection to the API to be de-serialized and sent on to the database?

Comment: The serialization is done by the `PostAsync()` method.